# Tomcat 9 on Windows Doesn't Read web.xml from Catalina_Home\conf on Startup

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9, catalina

After installing Tomcat 9 on Windows machine, the tomcat starts without any error but it doesn't service any servlet.

Using procmon, I found out that tomcat doesn't read the web.xml from %CATALINA_HOME%\conf when it starts.

It does read other files from that location such as server.xml

Any idea?

Comment: Look in the log files (`%CATALINA_BASE%\logs\catalina.2021-03-08.log`) for any errors.

Comment: Thanks but already checked and unfortunately no errors :-(

Comment: Can you add the `server.xml` file? Maybe you set `autoDeploy="false"` and `deployOnStartup="false"`.

Comment: autoDeploy="true" and deployOnStartup not exists
Do you need me to send you other stuff? I'll send everything later

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an upgrade from an older version (uninstall and then install) and the uninstaller have probably left some leftovers.

After I completely removed all the files and reinstalled everything worked